# Access variable globally in node js by using callbacks

Tags: php, node.js, callback

Is there any way to use `callbacks` for accessing the result outside the function or to use the result globally.
For example,

```
execPhp('sample_php.php', function(error, php, outprint){ 
  php.decode_key(fromUserId, function(err, fromId, output, printed){});
});
```

Here I need to get **output** value outside **php.decode_key** .
Can anyone help to find the solution?

Comment: And what is the problem, it seems that you are using `php-exec` module and I do not see wy this stuff shouldn't work, do you get any errors ?

Comment: It works perfectly but I need the output outside                                                  php.decode_key(fromUserId, function(err, fromId, output, printed){ 
          });

Answer (score 0):

The Ideea is that you can't use `fromId` outside the callback, it is calculated asynchronously (this code is spawning a `child-process` and he runs it in parallel of main code, in other thread of execution.)
A common example of use of PHP developers when they run into node is the following one:

```
var globalVar;
execPhp('sample_php.php', function(error, php, outprint){ 
   php.decode_key(fromUserId, function(err, fromId, output, printed){ 
      globalVar = fromId;
   });
});
```

Will not work, cause all the `async` method are runned in paralell they do not share the context (this is the asyncrhonous paradigm of javascript, concurency model)), so what you can do in this sense, is to write your code in the callback of the `php.decode_key` method.

A cleaner way can be to crete a module `keydecoder.js` and use it asynchornously in your main project:

```
//keydecoder.js
var execPhp = requiere('exec-php');

module.exports = function(fromUserId, cb) {
  execPhp('sample_php.php', function(error, php, outprint) {
    if (error) {
      cb(error);
    } else {
      php.decode_key(fromUserId, function(err, fromId, output, printed) {
        cb(err, fromId);
      });
    }
  });
};
```

and you can use it in this way:

```
var keyDecoder = require('../modules/keydecoder');

keyDecoder(fromUserId, function(err, result) {
   //use in main code
});
```